# In latest firebase cannot import EventContext from firebase-functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When i use `import {EventContext}` from `firebase-functions`the latest firebase throws and error:

> Cannot use import statement from outside a module.

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you resolve this? Do you have any answer?

Comment: Ross Rawlins: I did that a long time back. I simply changed my language from java to typescript. My scripts went well after that.